# Accordion Jquery collapse up onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a accordion, on click of which I want the accordion should collapse **UP**, now it is **collapsing down**. Any help. See my code below:-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion({
            header: "h3",
            collapsible: true,
            active: false
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also see the HTML code for the same:-

```
 <div id="accordion">
      <h3>Section 4</h3>
            <div>
                <p>
                    Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia
mauris vel est.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
inceptos himenaeos.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Seems to collapse "up" to me? http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/97qqgoat/ and then "expands" down

Comment: @RobSchmuecker: I dont want like that, I want whenever I click on the div, the content should move UP. Currently it is moving down

Comment: @RobSchmuecker:Also.. I want only one tab, i dont want 3-4 tabs. The only main thing is that the content should Move UP.

Comment: so you want the content to move "up" but where should the header stay?  It would need a custom implementation of `accordion` i reckon.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker: Exactly, the header should move down. Yes, that needs some custom implementation of `accordion`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could just rotate them with css

```css
.accordion{transform:rotate(180deg);}
.accordion h3,.accordion div{transform:rotate(180deg);}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97qqgoat/3/)

Comment: Thanks Billy, just wanted that, but Can I get for Only `ONE` div ?

Comment: yes you can see here [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97qqgoat/6/). You could either add a class to the ones you want upside down or get it by selector as I have in the new fiddle that makes just the first go up and the rest go down.`.accordion:first-of-type ,.accordion:first-of-type h3,.accordion:first-of-type div {transform:rotate(180deg);}`